# Rendering THREE.Points as spheres

Tags: javascript, three.js

The old `ParticleSystem` has been renamed to `THREE.Points`. All the examples I have seen so far are nicely displaying particles as cubes on a black background.

Is it possible displaying spheres instead of cubes on a white background? Can anyone please point me to a piece of code doing this?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_billboards_colors.html)?

Comment: Something like that, but on a white background.